# Monitor Postgres db queries

Tags: database, postgresql, logging, monitor

Is there an easy way to monitor Postgres db queries in a (Windows XP) environment. I'm testing some new code and suspect that in some cases queries are being duplicated/repeated under certain conditions.

What is the easiest/best way to do this - I just need something simple - basically the timestamp and syntax of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following line into the config file:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

After a restart your logfile contains all statements.

Comment: A restart is not necessary. `pg_ctl reload` should be sufficient